# ngclass does not apply

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create a div that will change its size based on a variable within scope.  (angular 1.7.8)

I have
`<div ngClass="{{getClass()}}">` and I believe the function is binding correctly because when I load the web page and inspect the element it shows

```
<div ngclass="{"column-20":false,"column-25":true}">
```

For reference the getClass function looks like this

```
$scope.getClass = function() {
            return {'column-20': $scope.<thing> != "value",
                'column-25': $scope.<thing> == "value"}
        }
```

Even though it seems to be showing the correct logic I am not seeing the class applied to the div.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngClass doesn't work in this way.

ngClass activate a class if some related model is true. For your example:

```
<div ng-class="{'column-20': thing1,'column-25': thing2}">
```

somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.thing1 != "value"
$scope.thing2 != "value"
```

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Edit: hyphen works with single quote

Comment: I also needed to change my syntax from ngClass -> ng-class